# Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: codeigniter

I get the following error

> "Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php"

I have codeigniter 3 with hmvc(works fine until i try to do `modules::run()`).

this is my welcome controller:

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{
    protected $data;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('welcome_model', 'model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        modules::run('blog/cacat');

        $this->data['client_ip'] = $this->clientIP();
        $this->twig->display('welcome_message', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hey udemy i have also face such problem ... 
let you have controller and you have add one method called user to it 
and when you  call the model having also one method called user then both method of controller and model will conflict and you will got the above error ...

to overcome it simply do not keep same name for controllers method and models method

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit `third_party/MX/Modules.php` with following code.

`-` should be remove and `+`  should be add.

```
-       log_message('error', "Module controller failed to run: {$module}/{$method}");
+
+       $error_message = "Module controller failed to run: {$module}/{$method}";
+
+       if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') && ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
+           return ($error_message);
+       } else {
+           log_message('error', $error_message);
+       }
    }
```

As well as calling method should be

```
modules::run('Module/Controller/Method');
```